# Can a backbone.js constructor return a subclass?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js

We have a Backbone View superclass with six subclasses extending it.  Each subclass is for rendering a specific Model type.  The superclass itself is not really a useful thing to instantiate.  But it would be very handy to be able to call that superclass constructor with a Model, and have it return a View of the correct subclass for the model provided.  Can such a thing be done with Backbone?

Comment: How about using [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)? Add a method to the base class that accepts a model as an argument and returns a properly invoked view subclass?

Comment: You don't have easy access to the constructor function with Backbone so a factory method will be easier.

Comment: The factory method pattern would probably be ideal, except we want to maintain backwards compatibility with existing code that just calls 'new'.  (This abstract View superclass and its subclasses used to be a single class with a giant if/then/else tree in it.)

Comment: This ^ is why it's a REALLY good idea to use factories  from the start, especially when using inheritance. Encapsulated instantiation = freedom of choice.

Comment: What would that let me do that this doesn't let me do?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it working by defining a 'constructor' function that figures out if it's being called directly or through inheritance by checking for 'templateName', a property that all my child classes define.  If it's being called directly, it creates a new object of the desired type and returns it; otherwise it defers to its parent constructor.

What I learned today: it's a handy JS feature that if a constructor returns an object, that object replaces 'this' and becomes the new object.

[Canonical doc on the JS new() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)

My constructor looks like this:

```
constructor: function(options){

 // without a model we can't know what class to be.
 if (_.isUndefined(options) || _.isUndefined(options.model) || ! options.model.has('type'))
  throw new Error('new ThingView() called without a valid model.');

 // Because we're replacing ourselves with a subclass, constructor will execute twice.
 if (! this.templateName) { 
  // first time through: replace ourselves with a child
  var viewName = 'AssetAttributeView_' + options.model.get('type');
  return new Views[viewName](options); // replace ourselves with one of these

 } else { 
  // second time through: apply our parent's constructor.
  Backbone.View.apply(this, arguments);
 }
}
```